# wmic cpu get LoadPercentage always returns empty value

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmi, cpu-usage, wmic

I'm use wmic command to get current CPU utilization, the command are:

```
wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value
```

It's works fine at first, but somehow it doesn't shows the LoadPercentage, but always returns with empty result like:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value


LoadPercentage=
```

It's so weird and I'm pretty sure that the result don't match with the `taskmgr.exe`. I also tried this command without `/value`, the result is still the same.

I have copy a large file in my server, and the CPU usage in TaskManager and wmic is like:

[image]

no matter what value is in TaskManager, the wmic always return empty value.

Comment: It seems this happen when the percentage is zero, that is, it show `LoadPercentage=` instead of `LoadPercentage=0`

Comment: No, my system's CPU load is not zero and I have monitored the TaskManager, it's CPU load is not match with wmic's result.

Comment: I believe Aacini is correct. I was able to get `LoadPercentage=` once out of ~30 tries on my PC. I also occasionally see CPU usage of 0% in task manager. The value is transient and variable, so trying to match WMIC value with task manager seems impossible.

Answer (score 6):

I understand that this is an answer for a necro post. But as I can't see any correct answer here, the solution is `lodctr /R` . This command will reload counters. Must use a capital R, lower case 'r' returns an error. Remember Admin Privs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned **powershell** query for the same:

```
gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor | select PercentProcessorTime
```