# Getting CPU load from WMIC working only from prompt but not via call using exec() in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, cmd, load, exec

I need a function that will work on Windows 10 that will fetch my server's current CPU use.

I came up with:

```
function get_server_load() {
    exec('wmic cpu get loadpercentage', $cpuload);
    //print_r($cpuload);
    return $cpuload;   
}
```

For all intents, this should work with no issue. however, my API spits out a string like this:

> {"status":true,"message":"OKAY","cpu_use":["LoadPercentage","","",""],"mem_use":""}

If I use the same command in cmd.exe, as 'wmic cpu get loadpercentage', I get the expected output:

> LoadPercentage 12

Its almost as if `exec()` is ignoring the second line, because it's returning the "`LoadPercentage`" string but no numeric values. In my API Example, I should also note that the server has a pair of `dual quad-core Xeon CPUs` which explains the extra set of quotes.

That isn't the cause of the issue, however, as I can independently verify the issue exists on another machine that uses a single `FX6350 CPU`. In that machine, I use a separate install of Windows 10, IIS, PHP 5.6, install the API there, and get this output:

> {"status":true,"message":"OKAY","cpu_use":["LoadPercentage","",""],"mem_use":""}

I am intentionally CPU mining, to test CPU load- even at 100%, the API contains nulls.

For inclusion reasons, here is the call to the get_server_load() function (please note the memory info is intentionally commented out at this time.:

```
public function general_get(){

    $this->response([
        'status'  => TRUE,
        'message' => 'OKAY',
        'cpu_use'  => get_server_load(),
        'mem_use'  => ''//get_server_memory_available()
    ], 200);    
    //echo phpinfo();
}
```

If I have left any relevant data out, please ask, but I cannot figure out why I am getting null values in the PHP version.

I want to specify, unlike the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503084/wmic-cpu-get-loadpercentage-always-returns-empty-value), I am not trying to match WMIC value to the task manager value. I am trying to make the actual WMIC value show up inside the PHP variable.

Comment: Should you not be using `shell_exec()`?

Comment: I seem to get the same result with both.

Comment: Do you know that `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe` always outputs text UTF-16 Little Endian encoded which of course must be taken into account on capturing and processing this output by PHP script code?

Comment: BTW: A Stack Overflow search with [\[php\] get cpu load](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+get+cpu+load) returns currently 399 results. There are many questions found with accepted answers. So it looks like others have successfully solved this task with PHP and you would just need to read their solutions.

Comment: @Mofi I appreciate your help, but, I should note that of those 399, I’d tried 300 ways, including using COM class calls, but always resulting with no valid cpu load string. However the bit about the string encoding is maybe something I can work with.